# How do I Include ObjectiveC files in FreePascal for iPhone Development with Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, ios5, delphi-xe2, freepascal

I need to add 2 files, a .h and a .m file to the FreePascal system.  I have read the articles related to parsing the headers, and dowloaded the parse-ios tools.  I keep getting "Unrecognized Framework" error when I run the parse-ios.sh
As I am a newbie to using the Delphi XE2/FPC/XCode combination, any help would be most useful

Comment: Wow.  This sounds like a disgusting set-up. I like it!  :-)  Are you doing this within Xcode on a Macintosh or somewhere else?

Comment: I am using Delphi XE2 to code an iPad app. Indy, which is my weapon of choice for network connectivity, is not supported for iOS yet.  I have an ObjectiveC unit which has been recommended for FTP functionality. I now need to get the FreePascal compiler (which used for compiling the .Pas stuff) to recognise this unit.  There should be a way, I'm probably missing the bus on something.

Comment: (Afaik Delphi XE2 exports a XCode project, that is then compiled on an intel Mac to iOS. So this question is probably about how to modify the exported project to link to objective C)

Comment: @Marco, that's about the size of it. The XE2 creates an XCode project with .pas files, which are then compiled using a custom script by FPC.  My challenge is linking an ObjC file into the project. As I said in an earlier comment, it is probably quite easy once you know how.

Answer (score 0):

Free Pascal does not compile C/C++/Objective C or its headers. It can link to Objective C code though given proper (Objective Pascal) headers.

So you need to use an Objective C compiler to compile the Objective C *code*, and create an header in Objective pascal to describe the bits you need to access.

The best place to start is probably the Free Pascal/Lazarus wiki, and studying the Cocoa objective Pascal units (and their Objective C respective headers they were translated from) that come with Free Pascal. I'm not sure what XE2 exactly packages from the FPC standard distribution though.

You might also risk a post on the [Mac-pascal](http://lists.sonic.net/mailman/listinfo/mac-pascal) list, though it seems inactive the last two weeks (moderated list with the moderator on holiday?), so be patient.

Comment: And embarcadero of course, since this setup is primarily theirs.